# React Admin: Can I use another field for <ReferenceInput>, other than "id"?

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest, react-admin

**Is there any way to use a different reference field (other than `id`) for a `ReferenceInput`?**

For example:
I have a `languages` resource, which I want to populate using a `language_code` field.
Note, I don't want to use the `id` field of `languages`, I want to use the `code` field.

I have managed to get it to work by using the following:

```js
<ReferenceInput 
  label="Language code" 
  source="language_code" 
  reference="languages"
>
  <SelectInput optionText="name" optionValue="code" />
</ReferenceInput>
```

The only problem with this is that:

After selecting a language from the select input, the `ReferenceInput` tries to fetch the resource using the `code` field rather than the `id` field, which returns a 404 error.

Comment: Do you mean it tries to fetch using the `id` field instead of the `code` field ?

Comment: No, it uses the `code` field (I assume because the `optionValue` is set to `code` so it populates the `ReferenceInput` with the code). So it fetches `languages/en` rather and `languages/1`. This fails because the `languages` endpoint expects an `id` in the URL and not a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value stored as the reference to the `languages` in the resource **must** be its identifier. Indeed, if you add a `ReferenceField` in the show view of your resource, how can it fetch the language without its id ?

You have two options here:

- make your API support the `languages/en` route
- store the `language_id` in addition to the `language_code` in your resource and create a custom `ReferenceInput` which will return both values after selection

Answer (score 0):

> **Do we know the underlying reason why we use "id" field for the `<ReferenceInput>`?**
>
> On that note, [here's an official explanation from react-admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#referenceinput).
>   IMO, if we catch that bit from `react-admin` then we can (try to) use any other field, maybe !

In your case,  fetches data, and delegates rendering down to `<SelectInput>` to which it passes the possible choices as the choices attribute. This works fine since you are able to select a "language".

> Are you aware that `optionValue="id"` is the default?

Two possible solutions:

- Remove `optionValue="code"`
- Can you find a way to map your `"code"` to an `"id"`? 
  Remember in this case `<SelectInput>` populates it's `choices` prop from `<ReferenceInput>`,
  `choices=[{id='', value=''}, {...}]`